# How would i add a widget to a StackLayout inside a ScrollView inside a FloatLayout?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Fairly new to kivy and only have a highschool education of python and have been stuck on this for a week now. I want a system where i can add and remove buttons in the StackLayout, how would i go about doing that?

I can add and remove the buttons I now just need to figure out how to place them in the correct area.

I understand this question is a bit of a clusterf*** and i have jumped in the deep end with this but i figured best was to learn is to dive right in to it.

pythton code:

```
# import kivy & functions/widgets.
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

# import kivy layouts.
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

# Specify version of kivy needed.
kivy.require("1.10.1")

# define buttons and widgets
testButton = Button(width=177, height=254, size_hint=(None, None), background_normal="pics/32864.jpg")


class Page(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def add_button(self):
        Page.add_widget(self, widget=testButton)


class YuGiOhApp(App):
    pass


YuGiOhApp().run()
```

My .kv code:

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<TestButton@Button>:
    width: 177
    height: 254
    size_hint: None, None
    background_normal: "pics/32864.jpg"

FloatLayout:

    Button:
        size_hint: 0.20, 0.10
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.60, "top": 1}
        text: "Search"
        on_press: root.add_button()

    Button:
        size_hint: 0.20, 0.10
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.80, "top": 1}
        text: "collection"

    TextInput:
        multiline: False
        font_size: 48
        size_hint: 0.60, 0.10
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 1}

    ScrollView:
        size_hint: 0.60, 0.90

        StackLayout:
            orientation: "lr-tb"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 0.88}
            size_hint: 1, None

            height: self.minimum_height

            padding: 5
            spacing: 5

            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
```

Edit 4: Getting the error "AttributeError: 'FloatLayout' object has no attribute 'add_button'" when trying to run the add_button() function when the button labeled "search" is pressed

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The answer to your question is likely to depend on code you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

First, your `kv` refers to `FloatLayout`, when it appear that you really want to reference your `Page` class. (You reference `root.add_button()`, but that method is in the `Page` class).

Second, your `testbutton` is a single instance of `TestButton`, so the second time you click on the `Search` button, you would get an error about that button already having a parent. So I created a `TestButton` class in the python code and removed the `<TestButton@Button>` rule from the `kv`.

Here is what I think you want for your code:

```
# import kivy & functions/widgets.
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button

# import kivy layouts.
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

# Specify version of kivy needed.
kivy.require("1.10.1")

# define buttons and widgets
class TestButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.width = 177
        self.height = 254
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.background_normal = "pics/32864.jpg"


class Page(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def add_button(self):
        self.ids.stack.add_widget(TestButton())



class YuGiOhApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Page()


YuGiOhApp().run()
```

And add an `id` for your `StackLayout` in the `kv`:

```
#:kivy 1.10.1
<Page>:

    Button:
        size_hint: 0.20, 0.10
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.60, "top": 1}
        text: "Search"
        on_press: root.add_button()

    Button:
        size_hint: 0.20, 0.10
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.80, "top": 1}
        text: "collection"

    TextInput:
        multiline: False
        font_size: 48
        size_hint: 0.60, 0.10
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 1}

    ScrollView:
        size_hint: 0.60, 0.90

        StackLayout:
            id: stack
            orientation: "lr-tb"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 0.88}
            size_hint: 1, None

            height: self.minimum_height

            padding: 5
            spacing: 5

            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
            TestButton:
```

The new `add_button()` method refers to the new `stack` id to access the `StackLayout` and creates a new `TestButton` each time it is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can give your `StackLayout` widget a unique `id`.

```
StackLayout:
    id: your_stacklayout_id
    ...
```

Then to access your `StackLayout` widget, you can use its `id` inside your `root` widget.

```
#: import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

FloatLayout:

    ...

    Button:
        text: "Add new Button"
        on_press: root.ids["your_stacklayout_id"].add_widget(Factory.TestButton())

    ...
```

Here is a basic example:

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import *
from kivy.uix.button import *

class Main(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

TestApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
#: import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MyButton@Button>:
    text: "Added Button"

<Main>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            text: "Add New Button"
            on_press: root.ids["my_boxlayout_id"].add_widget(Factory.MyButton())

        BoxLayout:
            id: my_boxlayout_id
            orientation: "vertical"
```